# Spring Cloud Eureka UI could not get client side ip address when add management.port

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

Here are the steps I followed:

1. I changed `management.port` to 5001 in Auth-Service application (`server.port` is 5000)
2. I kept the default value for `management.port` in A-Service application (`server.port` is 5100)
3. I configured the following properties in these two applications:

   ```
   eureka:
     instance:
       prefer-ip-address: true
     client:
       serviceUrl:
         defaultZone: http://registry:7000/eureka/
   ```
4. I checked the application status in Eureka UI, A-Service could get the right IP address when I click the status. But the Auth-Service status URL is still using host names in stead of IP addresses.

[image]
[image]

My question is how to change the Auth-Service status link to IP instead of hostname when I change the `management.port`? Which configuration am I missing?

Comment: All it is displaying is the unique id. IP vs hostname is independent of `management.port`.